# Fourier series for $f(x) = |x|$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

I am trying to find the Fourier series for $f(x) = |x|$ on the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$ extended periodically with period $2\pi$.

I know that $a_0 = \displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$. I am having trouble with $a_n$.

I know the formula for $a_n = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)$ cos$(nt)$ $dt$

So plugging in: $a_n = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |t|$ cos $(nt)$ $dt$

I am having trouble with this integral. I know I have to use integration by parts which I know how to do. I am just stuck integrating $|t|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate it piecewise. Since $|t|$ is $(-t)$ on $[-\pi,0]$ and is $t$ on $[0,\pi]$, you have
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|t|\cos nt\; dt = \int_{-\pi}^{0}(-t)\cos nt\; dt + \int_{0}^{\pi}t\cos nt\; dt$$

Or, since the integrand is even, you could just say

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|t|\cos nt\; dt = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}t\cos nt\; dt$$

They are the same thing, if you simplify the first one a little bit.

Comment: am i correct that $b_n = 0$?

Comment: Yes. The $a_n$ are coefficients of even components, and the $b_n$ are coefficients of odd components. If $f$ is even (which it is), it has only even components and so all $b_n=0$. If $f$ is odd, then similarly all $a_n=0$. And if $f$ is neither even nor odd, there will be some nonzero $a_n$'s and some nonzero $b_n$'s (not necessarily for the same $n$ though).

Answer (score 2):

This is an even function.

\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac1{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |t|\cos(nt) \, dt \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi t \cos(nt) \, dt
\end{align}

We have removed the absolute value sign, can you complete it?

Comment: why is this an even function?

Comment: Let $h(t)=|t|\cos(nt)$, verify that $h(-t)=h(t)$.

Comment: since it is $|t|$ they are equal...got it

Comment: am i correct that $b_n = 0$?

Comment: yes, for an even function, $b_n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(t)$ is an even function, so the coefficients of all of the sin terms will be even.

And for the cosine terms we can say

$\frac 1{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x| \cos nx \ dx = \frac {2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} x \cos nx \ dx$

Which we solve using integration by parts.

$\frac {2}{\pi}(\frac {\sin nx}{n} - \frac {1}{n^2} \cos nx) |_0^{\pi}$

If $n$ is even $\cos n\pi - \cos 0 = 0$

If $n$ is odd...
$a_n = \frac {4\cos nx}{n^2\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but since $f(-t) = f(t)$ then

\begin{eqnarray}
a_n 
&=& \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|t| \cos(nt)~{\rm d}t \\
&=& \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}t \cos(nt)~{\rm d}t \\
&=& \frac{2}{\pi}\left[\underbrace{\left.\frac{t}{n}\sin(nt)\right|_{0}^{\pi}}_{=0}-\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nt)~{\rm d}t \right] \\
&=& -\left.\frac{2}{\pi n^2}\cos(nt)\right|_{0}^{\pi} \\
&=& \frac{2}{n^2}[(-1)^n - 1] \\
&=& 
\begin{cases} 
0 &,& n~\text{even}\\
4/\pi n^2 &,& n~\text{odd}
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

And this is a little graph showing the sum

$$
\tilde{f}(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{n_{\rm max}} a_n \cos(n x)
$$

[image]